# Visualising data with boxes and adding circles/ticks to the boxes

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure

I have what seems like a simple task and would be very grateful if someone could lend a hand or point me in the right direction.

I have a vector of ones and zeros and I want to create a plot of this data in the following way: I want a vertical block of two squares and for each element in the vector, I would like to add a tally (this could be a circle, a dot, anything really) in each of the squares. So for eg the top square could tally all the 0's and the bottom square could tally all the 1's.

So for eg if I had a vector of 50 zeros and 50 ones, at the end of running this file, each block would contain 50 circles/tally markings. I have started by creating rectangles as follows:

```
axis([0 1 0 1])
rectangle('Position',[0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2])
rectangle('Position',[0.1,0.8,0.2,0.2])
```

But I am stuck when I want to actually add the tally marking to each circle according to whether the element of the vector is zero or one.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem seems to be how to distribute the tallies, circles, whatever in each of the boxes in a good-looking way. `Shai`'s answer is a good one up to a certain point. If you take that answer, I suggest you use semi-transparent symbols. That way the overlapping symbols will be visible.

Let us try this with `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# input vector with 100 elements:
v = np.random.randint(0,2,100)

# calculate the number of 0's and 1's:
n_zeros = np.sum(v == 0)
n_ones = len(v) - n_zeros

# create the plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0,2)
ax.set_ylim(0,4)
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((.5, .5), 1, 1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='k'))
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((.5, 2.5), 1, 1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='k'))

# calculate some random coordinates for zeros and ones
c_zeros = np.array([.6, .6]) + .8 * np.random.random((n_zeros, 2))
c_ones = np.array([.6, 2.6]) + .8 * np.random.random((n_ones, 2))

# plot ones with semi-transparent red
ax.plot(c_ones[:,0], c_ones[:,1], 'o', mfc=(1.,0.,0.,.5), mec='none', markersize=10)
# plot zeros with semi-transparent blue
ax.plot(c_zeros[:,0], c_zeros[:,1], 'o', mfc=(0., 0., 1., .5), mec='none', markersize=10)
```

We get:

[image]

This graph has two clear shortcomings:

1. Randomness does not give even distribution
2. The size of the markers is independent of the zoom level; if you zoom in, the marker size keeps at 10 points.

Number 2 is relatively easy to fix by using circles instead of the markers. (The code is just a bit simpler by using the markers.)

However, the other problem is a bit nastier. Most probably we would like to pack the circles into the rectangle so that their centers are as far away from each other as possible. This is known as the *packing problem*, and there are no simple solutions. The optimal packings are usually rather beautiful, but producing even a good approximation is mathematically rather challenging.

So, let us try something simpler. We will always draw our points in a grid with N rows and either N or N+1 items in each row.

```
def find_packing(num_items):
    """Find a reasonable packing of circles into a rectangle

    num_items - number of items to pack

    Returns: [list of X coordinates], [list of Y coordinates]
             - lists are normalized so that all coordinates are in the interval [0,1]"""

    # get rid of a few special cases:
    if num_items == 0:
        return [],[]
    if num_items == 1:
        return [.5], [.5]
    if num_items == 2:
        return [0., 1.], [.5, .5]
    if num_items == 3:
        return [0., 0., 1.], [0., 1., .5]

    # calculate the size of the full square (n >= 2)
    n = int(np.sqrt(num_items))

    # determine the required number of rows:
    if num_items > n * (n+1):
        num_rows = n + 1
    else:
        num_rows = n

    # determine how may elements we have beyond the full num_rows x n rectangle
    leftovers = num_items - num_rows * n

    # let us create a list of row lengths:
    r_lengths = [n] * num_rows

    # the leftovers need to be distributed evenly (note the integer division):
    for i in range(leftovers):
        r_lengths[(i * num_rows // leftovers + num_rows / 2) % num_rows] += 1

    # let us normalize the coordinates so that the resulting coordinates are always 0,0..1,1
    xcoords = []
    ycoords = []
    row_step = 1. / (num_rows - 1)
    for r in range(num_rows):
        ycoords += [r * row_step] * r_lengths[r]
        xcoords += np.linspace(0, 1, r_lengths[r]).tolist()

    return xcoords, ycoords
```

Now, this is easy to integrate into the plotting code:

```
# calculate some less random coordinates for zeros and ones
c_zeros = np.array([.6, .6]) + .8 * np.array(find_packing(n_zeros)).T
c_ones = np.array([.6, 2.6]) + .8 * np.array(find_packing(n_ones)).T
```

Then we make another slight change to our plot to keep the squares square:

```
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

This should be added before the `set_xlim` command.

With these changes our graph looks like:

[image]

(Here I changed the number of items in `v`to be 200 and odds being 0.33/0.67 to make it look more interesting.)

Answer (score 0):

You can plot circles (or squares) using [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) command. In order to avoid plotting all markers at the same spot, you may consider adding some randomness to the location.

The centers of the squares

```
c0 = [0.2, 0.4];
c1 = [0.2, 0.9];
```

suppose you have the following vector

```
v = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0];
```

A little randomness

```
r = 0.025*randn( numel( v ), 2 ); % you may control the "spread" of the markers using the scaling factor here

% do the plot
axis([0 1 0 1]); hold on;
rectangle('Position',[0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2])
rectangle('Position',[0.1,0.8,0.2,0.2])     
s0 = v == 0;
scatter( c0(1)+r(s0,1), c0(2)+r(s0,2), 20, 'ob' ); % blue circles
scatter( c1(1)+r(~s0,1), c1(2)+r(~s0,2), 20, 'ob' ); % blue circles
```